# 1 Gateway 2 Machines 2 Domains 3 Subdomains, How to

Tags: nginx

I had a working configuration in nginx for just one of my websites, but I broke it when I tried to make it work with 2 different domains, one of which has 2 sub domains, all serving different sites or applications.  To make matters harder on me, the domain running 2 apps is on a separate machine, and I am trying to proxy requests for that domain to the correct machine on my LAN. See below:

[image: My Architecture]

My NGINX config is a disaster, but is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/pi/sites/main;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html domain1_index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {

    root /home/pi/sites/main;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name internal.domain1.info; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.domain1.info/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.domain1.info/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
    if ($host = internal.domain1.info) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name internal.domain1.info;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
  server_name shiba.com www.shiba.com whispering.shiba.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://<machine2'sIP>:8888;
  }
}

server {
  server_name yelling.shiba.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://<machine2'sIP>:8555;
  }
}
```

How can I get this to serve websites as specified in my picture?
Thanks.

Edit: My proposed new configuration

```
|sites-available | symlink --> | sites-enabled
   conf1         |             |    conf1
```

```
#https website
server {
    root /home/pi/sites/main;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.domain1.info/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/internal.domain1.info/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
#http website redirect
server {
    if ($host = internal.domain1.info) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name internal.domain1.info;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
|sites-available | symlink --> | sites-enabled
   conf2         |             |    conf2
```

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name whispering.shiba.info;

    return 301 http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8555;
}
```

```
|sites-available | symlink --> | sites-enabled
   conf3         |             |    conf3
```

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name yelling.shiba.info;

    return 301 http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8888;
}
```

Comment: You're using default catchall `server{}` along with `server {}` that don't have `listen`. Thats probably why nothing is working properly. And yeah, part of the cause is that your config is a mess. Looks like you hate UNIX and nginx in particular. Everything looks so temporary and demoish.

Comment: @drookie It is demoish, it is my first config on my first project.  I wanted to hack my existing config, but I clearly don't know enough.  Do you suggest that I make seprate configs in the sites-available and symlink to sites enabled, or should I have one config with 3 servers for my whole architecture, or 1 config, 1 server and 3 locations?  I am having a hard time even searching for the preferred method of setting up a system like this.

Comment: Each server (vitualhost) should be put into its own config file. Never serve target sites with default server; it's should be used only as a place holder for catching misconfiguration. It is not as important if you put files into sites-available and then symlink them, but this is preferred method because it makes accidental config deletion less possible.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I edited my question with my proposed configurations.  My intuition is that this wont work since I am listening on port 80 3 times, and hence nginx won't even start.  Additionally, I'm not sure if just asserting server name will direct requests for yelling.shiba.info to xxx.xxx.x.xx:8555.  Do I need to do if ($host == yelling.shiba.info> { return 301 http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:PORT } as I show in my example?  Thanks.